How much easier/harder would it be to colonize space if humans found a method of giving ourselves bodies that could survive in almost anything?
For exact specifications, the bodies are not necessarily hard sci-fi. The astronauts/colonists/etc. still look either human or like something from human imagination, but are technically made of Charm Matter (like Strange Matter but with Charm Quarks) which the story assumes (regardless of any lack of evidence in real life) is basically a magic indestructible form of matter because reasons.
The method of creating these bodies and transferring a mind between the old biological body and the new is a solved problem that can be done extremely cheap, so assume that it is scalable but a very niche tech that cannot be applied in other contexts.
The artificial "energy slime" bodies would be able to survive everything short of a star (or rather, if they can survive a star, there's no way to detect and rescue "Quarks" from having fallen into the sun; gruesome, I know) or the event horizon of a black hole.
Quarks still have to sustain themselves via "charging stations"/"beds" at night and sunlight or consuming hydrogen during the day.
The doubt is "Does this actually make space travel easier? Or is it just wishful thinking?" but the question I'm asking is the title: "How much, if at all, would these transhuman bodies improve space travel?"
Feel free to give only the most basic explanations/resources, this isn't a "do my homework" scam. I'm a writer who is genuinely curious what would be possible if we didn't need as much protection as we currently do to live on other planets or moons. Unsolved problems of contemporary real life space travel and colonization that provide significant difficulty, and would not be made easier by making life support systems obsolete, would also be good to know of.

That's a lot of question you have in one post, and most likely will get this closed due to lack of focus. You're more likely to get your answer(s) if you break it up and focus on a single issue at a time.

That's fair. How about just the overarching question in the title, "Does this make it easier to go to space and by how much?"

That seems like a good start! You can always expand with follow up questions, but an all in one never really does well here.

Edited to let everyone know I'm just asking that one question for now. Is this okay?

I'd recommend keeping your question consice for now without any distractions. People are more likely to answer of they don't have to cut through the fluff. I recommend having a quick look at the help centre as well (question mark in the top right) to get an idea of what is expected.

I think you should try to condense the text to a few sentences and also keep track of your follow-up questions somewhere on your computer. Then think about the primary aspect that you see as "problem" or "doubt" in your scenario and try to pour this into a one-sentence-question at the bottom of the text. Does this make sense to you? (You can post more questions later, one at a time, not all at once)

Not hating your question at all btw, just trying to help out as you're new here and it can be a bit tricky getting started. I wish I knew enough about space travel to answer.

@Antares That's fine, I'll clip it. Thanks!

@Plutian No problem, I understand the rules are to keep up quality of answers and engagement.

Please don't get scared away if the question gets closed anyway. Just use the "improve question"/edit function. We will stay at your side here, just keep posting comments if you need further assistance. I think we will see if you updated the question, but a short notice in the comment does not hurt (I am offline for a few hours now).

@Antares Yup, I've shortened it and made it more concise. Thanks for the tips!

Keeping humans alive in space has been a solved problem for 60 years. Keeping humans alive in space is not what makes space travel difficult. For example, a trip to Mars and back with technology that we currently have and could use if we had the money and the will to do it would take 400 to 450 days: and we already know how to keep a person alive in space for that long, as both Valeri Polyakov and Francisco Rubio have shown.

@AlexP I was thinking a little more long term, as in 450 days, but to move your family/household to a different planet. Permanent residence seems to be impossible without significant changes, thus why the offer of "immortality for colonization" is being made.

@Gadg8eer: My point was simply that keeping the apes alive is not what drives the cost of space travel. Keeping the apes alive is relatively easy and cheap. It is everything else that is expensive and complicated.

@AlexP It's wildly misleading, at best, to suggest that just because it is possible to keep humans alive in space, the cost/risk isn't a significant factor in limiting manned space exploration.

@AlexP It is nowhere near a solved problem.  We know how to keep humans alive in space but at substantial ongoing cost.  If you had no life support or capsule costs think of how much easier Mars would be.  And between airless bodies you can probably actually use Verne's method to the moon.  (Think of the manhole cover in the Plumbbob test.)

Very much easier
I don't care so much about not needing an atmosphere or resisting heat or cold. These are detail problems, while live support is not trivial, its mostly a solved problem.
Immunity from radiation is much more useful, this enables missions that would be very hard to impossible otherwise.
But the real game changer is... immunity from time.
Look, the real show stopper for large scale space exploration is always said to be the speed of light. And the humongous amounts of energy needed to get just to a fraction of it. It just takes sooo long to go anywhere.
But what if "long" is something that does not matter anymore?
You could go to alpha centauri with todays technology, if you are willing to take the cost. And have a few thousand years to spare.
A few thousand years is nothing on cosmic scales, you could colonize the galaxy practically in the blink of an eye.
Immunity from boredom would be a good thing to also have, though.
Or maybe you happen to have some really effective sleeping pills.

Could probably do a lot better than a few thousand years to alpha cen (~0.1% c is abysmal). There's a lot of tech we're pretty sure will work but hasn't been practiced as there isn't a need yet.

You could presumably accelerate much faster without running risk of killing humans. Build a giant railgun in space, aim, shoot.

If they are indestructable you can just keep accalerating the whole way and plow into the planet. No need to slow down (other than not destroying the object you land on)

@Martijn: Or just impact on a moon if it has any. Get a nice ring system to boot :)

@BMF 0.1% c is insanely fast; it is 1 million km/h.  We've currently hit 0.024% c with the Parker Solar probe.  A problem with going much faster than 0.1% c is that the ISM starts looking really thick.  Hard alpha radiation is just ions of helium moving at 5% c; plowing through the ISM turns the low-density gas into hard radiation.

@Martijn the keeping accelerating might be a problem of fuel which is eventually going to run out.

Even if one could live forever, one who left a world on a many-centuries-long journey would be unlikely ever to return to a world that was anything like the one from which one had departed.

@BMF I was going of the speed of our current probes out there, like voyager, new horizons etc. Of course improvements are possible but thats the baseline.

@supercat Sure, but I guess its less of an issue if all your immortal friends are still alive and well when you return.

@LazyLizard: But would one's friends be waiting at home when one returned, or would they have found somewhere else to go?

@supercat I dont know, sounds like a story element the author has to decide on. Spaceflight surely isnt for everyone, even immortals. Its a long term commitment.

Space Marines: Attack!
You say we can have bodies that survive in any circumstance? So you are making Warhammer 40.000 Space Marines. And it takes a special type of enemies and circumstances to kill those: A self-adapting Hive-Mind with hyper corrosive blood, traitors, Mechs, undead living-metal robot skeletons, bioengineered semi-intelligent mushrooms that live for Waaaaargh or ancient space-elfs hiding away in tiny pockets between reality and hell and on planetoid-sized spaceships... Oh, and the last three mentioned species are by the way older than the earth, with the latter two being created specifically as weapons to fight the former.
So... if you give us all Space Marine Bodies, and indoctrination to not kill each other in the process, then we could very very easily start to colonize anywhere... if we are not rendered sterile in the process. Just remember: Space Marines might manage to grow a century or two old, but they do die of old age unless you freeze them for long travels.
Space Marines (or similar) as a storytelling vessel would be the classic übermensch as a narrative device. They are better at everything (or most things), but in the end, they are still humans, with human emotions and stresses.
<Necron Sounds.WAV>
The alternative is, that you just created something as close to the Necrons as you can be... and those are even harder to kill than Space Marines. True, 99.99% of them lost their soul when they became immortal regenerating robot skeletons, but they are nigh impossible to kill, as even if you do... they come back. Again and again.
To them, truly no surrounding is lethal. Vacuum? Radiation fields? Time? All no problem, just allow them to hibernate when they are not needed to preserve resources. Even a planet of molten stone won't stop them forever, it'll just slow them down a little.
Too bad that Games Workshop believes that this almost perfect species hates everything living, prefers the universe quite dead, their eldritch gods enslaved, and the creators of mankind and most other species extinct. But exactly here, in the motivation and creation of your robot-esque-species, is your leverage to turn the idea of eternal robots into your tool to tell a story:

Becoming a Quarkman could be a sacrifice to mankind as a whole, travelling to the stars a neverending duty to build a planetary base so that one day you may see your own genetic sample be used to clone a child of you and prosper on the world you built. This positive motivation should taint your storytelling.
Or is becoming a Quarkman a punishment, as part of you is erased in the process, leaving you in the artificial body always feeling the gaping hole of what used to be you(r soul)? Is it a strive for redemption or regaining what is lost? Or is it a slow path to insanity? In either case, this motivation should reflect on how the Quarkmen interact with normal humans - or their orders.
Do Quarkmen dream of Quark Sheep?


Didn't think of the fertility issue, you're right. The only population increase, if there is any, would be coming from Earth because the process doesn't account for reproductive ability. Under those conditions it would be unlikely that colonization would even be necessary beyond "investing in your own future" because even with a death rate of near-zero the birth rate will also be extremely low. (I did the research on population growth for a past idea and it currently looks like we're plateau-ing, not increasing, our population at well under the resource limits of what Earth could support.

@Gadg8eer If they are time-immune... you got Necrons. If not: Space Marines. Better freeze them during transport to keep death rate low.

As for Warhammer, I'd prefer not to go a grimdark direction with this but the clarification is appreciated.

@Gadg8eer You don't need to go grimdark, but Warhammer 40k is so over the top (that used to be a parody on everything btw), that that "these are the best of the best of the best" became a neat way to explore some parts of perfect specimens.

In other words: While I don't suggest to go Grimdark, exploring the ideas of what happens to such superhuman beings through the Grimdark lens in what it could do to the people is a worthy endeavor, especially as the answer to the question posed is almost a trivial Yes, because you are superhuman

That makes sense, thank you.

The W20k universe takes space colonization as an established fact, with space colonization been a millennia-old fact of life with little import on the actual universe. The survivalists you're mentioning here are designed for combat, not for colonization, so even these examples are not a good fit.

I can't speculate on your fancy matter, but I do know that conventional electronic circuits can work in liquid helium. Many circuits actually work better without thermal noise.
If you are travelling between the stars, most of the time your ambient temperature will be about 2 Kelvin. If you have an electronic brain, you can  work very well at these temperatures. If you have a superconducting brain, you will probably be able to run for ages on a tiny energy budget. Probably, most of you will go to sleep, while you run an error-checking program that may detect and correct damage from cosmic rays, and a clock to wake you up when you get there. You would have some sort of telescope to navigate by, and see details of your destination. When you aren't navigating, you could use it with a solar cell to generate a trickle of power to keep things going. Nothing should chemically degrade at those temperatures. A million years could pass and you would wake up just the same.
We can do all of this now, apart from the AI, and that is coming rapidly. Maybe the only missing bit is that AI has to exist long enough to have had a proper childhood. This will get you between the stars without needing any fancy matter.
Surviving at high temperatures is different. It is harder to do. It is only needed at the end of your long journey. You might keep a whole separate body to do that. Or you might make it from the matter you find when you get there. This is the better option as the lighter you and your craft are, the faster you can go.

Actually AI is not coming rapidly. The current generation of GPT-based AIs are essentially zero smarts, but excellent imposters. Good imposters are indeed new and noteworthy, even useful in some context, some of these even legit.


Many circuits actually work better without thermal noise. | that is false in our current reality. all integrated circuits are tested (and designed to work) in a temperature band and have very unspecified behaviour outside of those temperatures. dipping an IC in liquid helium can easily make gates that previously closed, unable to, and will definitely kill MEMS devices. However, given the tech this post already assumes, handwaivium ICs would easily survive ;)


I used to run Op Amps under liquid helium. I am not saying everything will work unmodified, but differential expansion effects should be small. I don't see why MEMS devices would definitely be killed, though this may be so. But this is not the point: I wanted to argue that some intelligence could survive for millions of years based on our current technology.

There are still many dangers to consider which make things difficult.
In the current scenario you have quasi-indestructible bodies, but everything else is made of normal matter.
Space Hazards and (Ship-)Infrastructure
Imagine the spaceship getting destroyed or otherwise wrecked in deep space (especially: communications, energy, propulsion, rescue shuttles). The bodies would be doomed to an eternal life in the endlessness of space. That could drive them crazy or trigger other things. If the power source is cut, you will need to know what happens to them if the chambers cannot provide recharging anymore (some kind of collective deep-sleep, mutiny/insurgence, fight for the remaining working chambers, and the like).
The bodies are also of finite size still, thus the spaceships need to be sized accordingly. All the challenges that come with this would not be alleviated. You need a dock where to build it, material, time, knowledge, man-power, etc. Technical failures occurring later would also not be excluded and they need maintenance.
Thus, making certain roles in the crew necessary for example engineers, while other roles can be dropped like chefs, doctors, etc (see below). Those still need universities and everything to get their knowledge from somewhere (on a home planet probably).
The things you would save are for example: Life support, maybe beds (and their space) because you could provide a large dorm room with those chambers (no need for privacy?), all the cargo space for foodstuff, kitchen areas, and medical/infirmaries, probably also bathrooms/toilets and other sanitation/waste. You probably still need entertainment, social and private areas for them and storage space for personal items, and important non-food items, like spare parts for the maintenance.
The space ships would have a very different layout than ours, because of the mentioned "superfluous spaces" that can be used otherwise. For example adding many sleeping chambers for large colony ships or something.
Prototype Scenario
The scenario reminds me of the Borg of StarTrek, concerning strengths and weaknesses (not appearance). I also like Trish's comparison to WH40k, very fitting extremes.
Power Source
There is one point to consider with the sleeping chambers and interstellar travel:
The ship needs a sufficiently capable power source which does not rely on sunlight alone. Or alternatively, you need a solution how to store a really large amount of energy (like large capacity batteries that were charged by solar energy). The reason is energy/light emitted from stars falls off rapidly with distance. It is already very faint just inside our solar system at the outer areas.
For example: Our Voyager1+2 which are the farthest away ("interstellar") objects in space we have contact to, do not rely on solar panels. They have a radio active power source to generate electricity.
I am not that familiar with the exact functionality, but I assume it goes something like this: There is a radio active source, emitting electrons, these are collected somehow and stored in a capacitor ("battery") until a sufficiently large charge has built up, then this is released into the circuitry gradually. If the battery is depleted, there is some time needed until it is charged again. Thus, you have a quasi-unlimited source (well, limited by the decay of the radio active material) for electrons but only available for certain phases with high amounts of pauses in between (which are timed in a way, that it is sufficient to send telemetry back to earth in regular time windows). "Always on" instruments need to have fitting "low energy profiles" to be powered by the (or a second) battery all the time.
Deadly Hazards
If they are vulnerable by "ripping apart" or "melting into plasma" or "being captured in a gravity well", there are other possibilities to "attack" them, which you would need to consider how this affects them. For example:

Cryogens "Freezing" attacks
Putting them into a particle accelerator
Confine/capture them deprived of recharging facilities
Attacks on their power supply infrastructure instead of their immortal bodies
Making a ship disabled and adrift (covert-ops, open attacks) and put it into a direct course into the nearest sun
Fancy anti-matter annihilations
Or just a software bug that prevents waking everybody up.

Conclusion
As LazyLizard covered in the answer: Immortal bodies would enlarge the possible travelling distances a lot (still taking long times). But their lives would not be "problem-free" and also not that "harm-free" - it shifts the attack vectors to something different. Mainly because of the infrastructure they still are dependent on. But maybe they are just peaceful traders instead of murderous conquerors.

Today's nuclear batteries (such as those used in Voyager) typically work by heat generation and use Peltier elements to convert them to electrical power. I doubt that capturing the electric charge in the radiation will work, because you need a lot of mass to do the actual capturing, and you'd still be wasting 99% of the energy since that's in the speed of the emitted particles.

One aspect to consider is the difference between the Easiness of space colonization, and the Comfort of it.
Sure, Your indestructible transhumans could be shot into orbit from a cannon, which would be far cheaper than rocketry. Then an orbiting spaceship could collect them like a dump-truck and haul them to Mars, drop them from orbit, and let them fend for themselves.
All in all, this would reduce the cost and hassle of Mars colonization by 99%.
But the process would be grueling, and the life on Mars absolutely miserable this way.
After all, the point of going to Mars, or any alien planet, is not to be trapped on a barren rock with dead wasteland stretching in all directions for all eternity, but to have a new HOME there. This means space cities, pressurized bases, and finally terraforming. Sure, your Quarks could survive on a barren frozen desert, but what would be the point of doing that? Life is not just about surviving, its about actual living. They would still want the atmosphere, even if they do not need to breathe. They would still want cozy warmth, even if they cannot freeze or burn. They would still want to surround themselves with plants and animals, even if they do not eat either.
So my guess would be that while the earliest colonization attempts would be easier, there would be far more pressure to start terraforming and provide comfort quicker. Fragile humans who live for a few decades at most can imagine just heroically struggling to survive on a tiny, spartan pressurized hub, and finally dying, but an immortal would logically know that this will become a nightmare after a while, and would demand creature-comforts upfront.

You can make ships out of charm too
If you can cheaply make something as complex as people out of charm, then you can use it to make your ships too.  No need for thick armor or complex landing systems.  You can just launch your ships and have them crash down on planets to "land" with their whole payload intact.
Stasis  Pods
Part of the big cost of space travel is the infrastructure of keeping a crew alive.  But if you could just tuck the crew into a tiny box and keep the frozen or drugged up for the trip, then you could remove several tons of infrastructure per person for the trip.  Humans can't survive cryostasis or long term chemical sedation, but your immortal guys should have not problem with it.  That said, this requires some assumption of vulnerability.  Like just because near absolute zero temperatures won't kill them does not mean they don't have a minimum functional temperature.
More Acceleration
One of the hard parts about interstellar space travel is that human bodies don't do sustained acceleration of more than 1-2G very well. Charm bodies mean that you can get away with launching people and equipment using cheap space cannons instead of complex rocket systems making local space exploration much cheaper.  Also, an indestructible ship and bodies could be an alternate solution to the inertia dampeners problem.  Currently, even if you could create and engine that lets you to accelerate past the speed of light, you're still limited by how fast you can accelerate. Currently, a ship capable of accelerating up to the speed of light would take almost an entire year to reach light speed... which sure, if you are talking about a light speed limit turns a 4ly trip into a 5 yr trip, no big deal... but what if your civilization  learns to break the speed of light.  If some trick of perpetual motion finally pans out, and you can accelerate as fast and as long as you want.  Well, now that 4ly trip is reduced to about 3 years at 1g of acceleration... but 3 years is still a pretty long time.  What if you could accelerate at 1000g or 10,000g? Now you could have interstellar travel that happens in hours or even minutes.
